# Could not find file 'C:\tfs\Source\mvc\TwitterBootstrapMvcLicense.lic'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use TwitterBootstrapMVC.  I installed and once try to run the application I get this error:  Could not find file 'C:\tfs\Source\mvc\TwitterBootstrapMvcLicense.lic'.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/Home/Installation

Step 2 indicates that you need to download the license there and put it in the root of your project.

Always helps to read the docs.